# How do I get the .NET Data Provider for SqlServer counter to show up in Perfmon

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Has anybody managed to get the ".NET Data Provider for SqlServer" to actually work within perfmon.exe.

I have a .NET app that uses nhibernate to interact with sql server 2005 db.  All I want to do is to view the NumberOfActiveConnectionPools, NumberOfActiveConnections and the NumberOfFreeConnections within perfmon.exe

How exactly I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app.config setting to enable these counters. Via [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ActivatingOffByDefault):

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
    <add name="ConnectionPoolPerformanceCounterDetail"
         value="4"/>
  </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```